# Random assignment 1s and 0s with a maximum

Tags: r, random, vector, sample

I have a dataset with two different columns (X and Y) that both contains the exact same amount of 0s and 1s:

```
0     1 
3790  654
```

Now I want to have column Y to contain an **exact** amount of 1733 1s and 2711 0s. But the 1079 extra 1s (1733-654) must be assigned randomly. I already tried the following:

```
ind <- which(df$X == 0)
ind <- ind[rbinom(length(ind), 1, prob = 1079/3790) > 0]
df$Y[ind] <- 1
```

But if I run this code, there is everytime a different number of 1s, and I want it to be **exactly** 1733 if I run it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this vector:

```r
x <- sample(c(rep(0, 3790), rep(1, 654)))

#> table(x)
#> x
#>    0    1 
#> 3790  654
```

What you need to do is randomly select the position of 1079 elements in your vector that equals 0, and assign them the value 1:

```r
s <- sample(which(x == 0), 1079)
x[s] <- 1

#> table(x)
#> x
#>    0    1 
#> 2711 1733
```

Comment: I have a follow up question. I want to do the samen thing, but now not with the assignment of a 1, but with the random assignment between 1 and 10. I hope it is just a small adjusment.